# Customized Poll List

Tags: web-part, survey, design

I have a requirement to create poll of the week. In that i have created a survey list but when i display it on the web part, it displays as a description for the survey and by clicking on respond to this survey it takes me to a new page.

What i wanna do is to show the questions and answers on that page only and the graph representation too.
Is this possible?
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done using *out-of-the-box* functionalities. The survey questions are the *"New item"* form of the *Poll list* and the dashboard is a different page as well. I don't have much experience with poll lists but my feeling is that are few customizable and most times don't reach what user expects. In my case, I used different approaches from 3rd party tools like *Nintex Forms* or *custom development*. Now, if you are using *Office 365* you have *Microsoft Forms* to create really cool surveys or use *Excel Online surveys* functionality as well.

Check this [link](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/06/20/microsoft-forms-a-new-formative-assessment-and-survey-tool-in-office-365-education) about *Microsoft Forms*, this [one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Surveys-in-Excel-hosted-online-5FAFD054-19F8-474C-97EC-B606FCDA0FF9) is for surveys using *Excel Online*, and [here](https://www.nintex.com/workflow-platform/nintex-forms) the official page for *Nintex Forms*.

Comment: ohh i don't think i have access to any of the softwares above that you have mentioned. Anyway i will give a look around and see what is achievable.
Thanks !